# Filtrar por una columna con el mayor valor, eliminado un dato repetido dentro del Dataframe

Tags: r, rstudio

Requiero una ayuda para el siguiente desafío en Rstudio tengo el siguiente Dataframe:

```
fecha    Ticket   Valor
*2019     88378     0*       ##Esta fila debe ser filtrada o eliminada
*2019     88378     1*
*2019     89342     0*        ##Esta fila debe ser filtrada o eliminada
*2019     89342     1*
 2019     67823     0
 2019     34526     0
```

Lo que busco es poder filtrar el `dataframe`, eliminando las guías repetidas pero  dejando el `ticket` que contenga el mayor `Valor` entre las guías repetidas, esto se repite más de 100 veces, a su vez si la guía no se repite el valor debe permanecer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes usando funcionalidad base como `aggregate()` para "agrupar" las filas por `fecha` y `Ticket` y obtener el valor máximo de `Valor`.

```
df <- read.table(text = "fecha    Ticket   Valor
2019     88378     0
2019     88378     1
2019     89342     0
2019     89342     1
2019     67823     0
2019     34526     0", header=TRUE) 

aggregate(Valor ~ fecha + Ticket, df, max)

  fecha Ticket Valor
1  2019  34526     0
2  2019  67823     0
3  2019  88378     1
4  2019  89342     1
```

Invocamos `aggregate(<formula>, <data.frame>, <funcion>)` la formula: `Valor ~ fecha + Ticket`, nos indica como queremos agrupar